# Using Foreign Key or Text in one table

Tags: sql, key, denormalization

I am making a match making site. The profile table has personal, academic, professional and other information. After searching for NOSQL, Database Denormalization and few other topics, I am little confuse about few columns. Shall I use foreign key or it will be better to keep values in one table where possible.
The columns are:

```
MaritalStatus
Religion
Community
Profession
```

I can make individual tables for these columns and then use Id from these tables as foreign key into main profile table or I can store values direct into main profile table.
What would be best approach if I need more speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question of speed depends on the queries that you're running.

In general, if you are designing an application, then you want to have reference tables for values.  You want marital status, for instance, to take on values such as "N", "D", "M", and "S", say, for "never married", "divorced", "married", and "separated".  You can store the full expansion in the reference table, with the code in the user table.

Such reference tables are also handy for things like supporting more languages and validating results.

I doubt that a few joins to small reference tables will have much impact on the speed of queries.  That probably shouldn't be your main concern, unless you reasonably suspect that you are going to hit performance issues.